# Visual Studio 2005 debugging Classic ASP, step into VB6 code running in VB 6

Tags: debugging, windows-7, asp-classic, visual-studio-2005

OK, here goes nothing.....

I have a Windows 7 Ultimate Hyper-V Virtual Machine running with Visual Studio 2005 to debug my legacy Classic ASP site.

This works a treat.

However, there are some ActiveX DLL's written in VB6 that I can also run, compile, and debug within the Visual Basic 6 SP6 environment.

They compile OK and when the ASP executes a CreateObject command they all work, but I need to get into the code from VS2005 when it hits the object creation in the Classic ASP, it does not flow into the VB6 environment.

Does anyone have an idea on what might be wrong?

Comment: well VB6 language is a complety different architecture from the VB.net that runs Visual studio 2005, debuggin a VB6 code into VS2005 is not possible due to the fact that VS2005 doesn't have the inner components to run and debug such language. In other words **you are out of luck**.

Comment: Sorry I think you mistook my question. I know that you cannot debug VB6 code in .Net, but my question is that I have VB6 code running in debug mode within the VB6 environment. Then I have Classic ASP code running in debug mode within VS2005. I wish to be able to debug the VB6 ActiveX code with the VB6 environment, not the VS2005. But when the  ASP code executes calls to the VB6 DLL running within the VB6 environment, it does not jump from VS2005 to the VB6 Environment.

Comment: yet, i think is not possible